# Meta query array - same order as specified order in value

Tags: meta-query, order

I have a custom Wordpress query that is using an array of product IDs that exist in an ACF field(these IDs do not line up with the Wordpress post IDs). I would like for the order of the returned posts to match the order of the array that is specified in the `meta_query` `value`. Here is what my meta query looks like:

```
$product_ids = array('3624', '1298', '430', '5629', '765');

$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'product_id',
        'value' => $product_ids,
        'compare' => 'IN'
    ),
);
```

So, for instance, in the returned results I want the first product to be product ID `3624`, and the last product to be `765`. Is there a way to order the query results so that the order of the returned posts matches the order of the array specified in the meta query? I tried leaving `orderby` blank, but that seems to default to sorting by post ID. I also tried setting `orderby` to `none`, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: out of interest, is there a reason you can't do this at the point you consume the data? i.e. get an unordered list and pick out the items you want from it in whatever order you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP to sort the results after the query (untested):

```php
$product_ids = array( 3624, 1298, 430, 5629, 765 );

$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'product_id',
            'value'   => $product_ids,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
) );

$posts_by_product_id = array();
$sorted_posts = array();

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    foreach ( $query->posts as $post ) {
        $product_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'product_id', true );
        $posts_by_product_id[ $product_id ] = $post;
    }

    foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
        if ( ! array_key_exists( $product_id, $posts_by_product_id ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $sorted_posts[] = $posts_by_product_id[ $product_id ];
    }

    $query->posts = $sorted_posts;
}
```

The `$query->posts` property will contain the found posts, ordered by product ID to match the order in `$product_ids`.

Comment: This works great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the post type is `product`, and `$product_ids` is a list of IDs of products that you want to retrieve, then you can do this rather simply (untested):

```php
$product_ids = array( 3624, 1298, 430, 5629, 765 );

$query = new WP_Query( array(
   'post_type' => 'product',
   'post__in'  => $product_ids,
   'orderby'   => 'post__in',
) );
```

Comment: Unfortunately the Product IDs are a custom field and are not in sync with the Wordpress post IDs, but this is definitely a good alternate solution if I can't find a way to sort by the product ID array index. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Ahh, that context is helpful. Will you please edit your question to make that clear?

Comment: Added additional context, thanks!